# AVI files dont play in VLC from ISO mounted disk

Tags: 12.04, vlc, iso

I noticed this problem many times and I would like to know if there is any solution.
So when I mount ISO files and try to watch some AVI files I got vlc errors.
If I copy and paste the same files from the mounted ISO files to any folder of my pc then VLC plays them great!
Isn't it strange?
Any solution for that?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `fuseiso` works without problems.

```
mkdir test
fuseiso test.iso test
```

Now you can play your file from the directory. Clean up afterwards:

```
fusermount -u test
rmdir test
```

Comment: Yes works really great!!! But what is the difference with the default "right click, mount volume" ? Thank you!